# How can I find the Windows Edition name

Tags: c#, windows, operating-system

How can I find the Microsoft Windows **(Os name)** for my c# application.

such as 'Windows 8 Pro' I mean the Edition from the os.

Comment: I donot think OSVersion distinguish among home, pro, ultimate

Comment: @Tilak then don't use OSVersion in the solution and use WMI like the link in the duplicate says.

Comment: Also see [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/73000/Getting-Operating-System-Version-Info-Even-for-Win). A little [google searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+get+operation+system+name) can go a long way

Comment: gunr2171 that's maybe a way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the operating system name from the registry but you need to query WMI for the architecture and the service pack information:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
...
private string GetOperatingSystemInfo()
{
    RegistryKey operatingSystemKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion");
    string operatingSystemName = operatingSystemKey.GetValue("ProductName").ToString();

    ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
    // query any machine on the network     
    ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\machineName\\root\\cimv2", options);
    scope.Connect();
    // define a select query
    SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("SELECT OSArchitecture, CSDVersion FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

    string osArchitecture = "";
    string osServicePack = "";

    foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
    {
        osArchitecture = mo["OSArchitecture"].ToString();
        osServicePack = mo["CSDVersion"].ToString();               
    }            
    return operatingSystemName + " " + osArchitecture + " " + osServicePack;                         
}
```

If you want more information from WMI, be sure to take a look at the `Win32_OperatingSystem` class on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thx for your answer, I want to test it now